# Understanding differences between Swift OOP and Java OOP

Tags: swift

I'm a student coming from a Java background. I'm learning iOS Development and going through the Apple SwiftUI tutorial. Specifically at this step: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation.

There is a file called ModelData.swift which is responsible for loading some data from a JSON file.

Its full contents are:

```
import Foundation

var landmarks : [Landmark] = load("landmarkData.json")

func load<T: Decodable>(_ filename :String) -> T {
    let data: Data
    
    guard let file = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)
    else
    {
        fatalError("where is my \(filename)?")
    }
    
    do{
        data = try Data(contentsOf: file)
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("Problem loading this \(filename)")
    }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
    catch
    {
        fatalError("This file: \(filename) did not parse to type")
    }
}
```

What confuses me here is that there is no class declaration like there would be in Java. It seems like the *landmarks* variable and *load* function are just existing on their own. Is Swift not a strictly OOP language?

Secondly, the *landmarks* variable is used later in the tutorial without any instantiation  of a class. Another class simply uses *landmarks[0]* without any prior instantiation. In Java, the calling of *load* to populate *landmarks* would happen when the constructor of *landmark*'s parent class was called (to instantiate the class)? In Swift, when does the population of the *landmarks* array happen - is it when the variable is first used?

Comment: swift is not strictly OOP language. It supports OOP, functional programming, POP and more

Comment: Swift is not a strictly OOP language. `landmarks` is a global variable and `load` is a global function.

Comment: You should continue with the tutorial instead and some or all of your questions will be answered. Later on in the tutorial a class is created and the array is moved into that class as a property.

Comment: This particular code sample is using a global variable and global method (not part of any class or struct) to provide test data for the rest of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It uses generics the type comes from `var landmarks : [Landmark]` that conforms to `Decodable`.

https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/generics/

The constructor/initializer is called by the `JSONDecoder` `Decodable` requires `init(from:)` in this case it is set at creation.

`Decodable` is a `protocol` or `interface` in Java.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/decodable